# Find specific patterns in logfile with grep

Tags: grep

I try to grab some activities in a logfile with grep.

The logfile looks like the line below:

```
[07/16/2019 14:09:26:516 CEST] 00018e0a main I [APPName][DEBUG][Various Activity Name][SERVICE] node: <resultSet recordCount="3" columnCount="6">
```

So my target is to grab over the logfile and get all activity names (various and sometimes unknown names).
I tried with regex but I can't reach the final goal :-P.

How can i grab like (here comes my pseudoCode):

```
grep "[AppName][DEBUG] [*]" logfile.log
```

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using sed for this. Just make sure that you are escaping characters properly. Something like this should work and you can pipe it to sort and uniq to get a unique list of activity names:

```
sed 's/.*\[APPName\]\[DEBUG\]\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/' logfile.log|sort|uniq
```